# Phantom JS to eliminate margins from screen capture

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization, phantomjs

I am trying to screen-capture the HTML file using PhantomJS.

[image]

When I run this capture with `phantomjs my.js`, PNG has margins of tiles as shown in the image.

Is there any way that I can delete all the margins so that I can see only graphs?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('/my/path/my.html', function() {

    page.viewportSize = { width: 700, height: 550 };
    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 700, height: 550 };
    page.paperSize = { width: 700, height: 550, orientation: 'portrait', margin: '0px' }

    page.render('my.png');

    phantom.exit();
});
```

And here's my html file with Google chart.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "PNG has margins of tiles that do not show in this StackOverflow page.", so how are we supposed to understand what you are talking about? What do you mean by "margins of tiles"? Draw something for us if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your donut chart has a white `background-color` whereas the `body` element of your page has a transparent background:

```
body {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

*Source: your webpage.*

1. Note the margin associated to your `body` element. It corresponds to the top and left "margins of tiles" that you can see on your screenshot.
2. On the web, the margin of tiles represent transparence. To fix this, you should set the `background-color` to `white`.

---

Add the following to your CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Or, just above `</head>`, add this line:

```
<style>body { background-color: white; }</style>
```